# Consul cluster stack configuration

Tags: docker, consul, docker-stack

I'm trying to build Consul cluster stack. My current configuration works fine, but after restart consul leader or full stack, cluster have a problem to vote for a new leader.

After service restart, new task have a different ip address for same node-id.

Is any parameter for consul agent configuration to fix address change in cluster?

Below my current stack definiotion

```
version: '3.5'

services: 
  consulLeader:
    image: consul
    volumes:
      - consul_l_data:/consul/data
    command: 'agent -bind "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}" -bootstrap-expect 3 -client 0.0.0.0 -ui -server -node nodeLeader -retry-join consulNode1 -retry-join consulNode2'
    environment: 
      - "CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={\"skip_leave_on_interrupt\": true,\"leave_on_terminate\": true}"

  consulNode1:
    image: consul
    volumes:
      - consul_n1_data:/consul/data
    command: 'agent -bind "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}" -disable-host-node-id -client 0.0.0.0 -ui -server -node consulNode1 -retry-join consulLeader -retry-join consulNode2' 
    environment: 
      - "CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={\"skip_leave_on_interrupt\": true,\"leave_on_terminate\": true}"

  consulNode2:
    image: consul
    volumes:
      - consul_n2_data:/consul/data
    command: 'agent -bind "{{ GetInterfaceIP \"eth0\" }}" -disable-host-node-id -client 0.0.0.0 -ui -server -node consulNode2 -retry-join consulLeader -retry-join consulNode1'
    environment: 
      - "CONSUL_LOCAL_CONFIG={\"skip_leave_on_interrupt\": true,\"leave_on_terminate\": true}"

  # loadballancer
  nginxForCluster:
    image: nginx
    deploy:
      replicas: 1
      placement:
        constraints:
          - node.role == manager
    configs:
      - source: consul_nginx.conf
        target: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
        mode: 0440
    ports:
      - 8080:80

configs:
  consul_nginx.conf: 
    external: true
volumes:
  consul_l_data:
  consul_n1_data:
  consul_n2_data:
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your cluster does not elect a new leader after restarting the leader. Don't expect that the container that you call `consulLeader` to be the next leader as the raft protocol will elect the new leader out of your server pool where `consulLeader`, `consulNode1` and `consulNode2` should be the same. Try to configure them the same too, I can see differences in the config. Maybe that helps.

As workaround to unblock you you can also set fix IP's for the container in the compose file:
https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#ipv4-address-ipv6-address